Angular - react to changes in rxResource()
How one can react to changes / perform side-effects when rxResource receives .value() instead of using effect()?
Current approach in component:
  constructor() {
    this.service.setItemId(1); //setting signal
    effect(() => // work with data from async post request 
  } 

in service:
 resource$ = rxResource({
    request: () => this.itemID$(), // signal 
    loader: ({ request: id }) => {
      return this.http.post('http://');
    }
  }); 


what is the side effect you are trying to do?

Why don't you want to use an effect? With the given information it seems like it's the perfect choice for your use case.

I have lots of logic inside: performing http request, and based on the result mounting to a template nativeElement, etc...

UPDATE:
As per the requirements, it looks like you want to react to the creation of a new item in the database, but fetching the elements from the database reactively.
In the below code, we trigger the post on change of itemID$ value, I have used a modal here, this updates the database (PUT) and then we need to read the data to see if it is updated.
updatePost: ResourceRef<any> = rxResource({
  request: () => this.itemID$(), // signal
  loader: ({ request: id }) => {
    console.log(id);
    return this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/posts/1`, {
      id: 1,
      title: `from resource - ${id}`,
      views: id * 200,
      userId: 1,
    });
  },
});

All you need to do is pass the this.updatePost.value() signal execution as a input to the request method, this will trigger the GET api call (getPosts resource), on each post request from the rxResource (updatePost)
getPosts: ResourceRef<any> = rxResource({
  request: () => this.updatePost.value(), // signal
  loader: (params: ResourceLoaderParams<any>) => {
    console.log(params.request);
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/posts`);
  },
});


In the below stackblitz, we update a row in the database, then we get the rows, we can see that the row has been updated.

Open new terminal in stackblitz and run npx json-server db.json.

Then restart the angular server and click on localhost:4200 in the terminal to view the app in the preview and try out the feature.


Stackblitz Demo


If you want to derive state from the original signal, then you can use computed, linkedSignal to do this.
But since you are doing DOM manipulations based on an API call, the best option is to use effect to do this, else you can try to achieve the same result without any DOM manipulations.
constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    // .. DOM manuipulations.
  })
}

Ideally you should be able to achieve the same result without DOM manipulations based on signal reactivity, but those details need to be provided for a clear answer.

and how to proceed without effect() for another http request - in computed()? I thought it is for simple calculations.

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov updated my answer, can I update your question to how to make another API call based on changes from a rxResource value change?

I would like not in the service but in the component to perform logic:
from the component to track whether there are changes in the rxResource() (provided by the service), like information from the post request, and then to act on it once again in the component.

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov you can move the http post and get to the service, but the concept stays the same, the first API call, triggers the second API call, based on what to trigger the change, you can set in the equal property of rxResource.

agree, but I would like to do this in more controllable way like in effect() to direct which after which to be called, to perform template changes etc. With the above approach one signal is linked to another leading to cascade of changes/requests.

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov The template changes can be done by using angular control flow like @if, @for due to lack of proper details I am unable to help you, computed can be used to control these if conditions and achieve the desired output.

I would like to avoid the usage of effect():
in component we have:
 constructor() {
   this.stripeService.setItemId(1); // 1) we set the id,
   effect(() => this.setup());
 }

 private setup() {
   const { data } = this.myResource.value() ?? {}; // 4) use the data
 }```

 in service:
``` myResource$ = rxResource({
   request: () => this.itemID$(), //  2) trigger the request
   loader: ({ request: id }) => {
     return this.http.post('http:', id); // 3) async get the data
   }
 }); ```

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov but using thsi concept you can achieve what you want, just use the effect for DOM manipulation and rxResource to perform the API calls, either on a component or a service,
